# Pass string of HTML page and scrape with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, vb.net, html-agility-pack

Why do I get this error?

> "Illegal characters in path" at `htmlDoc.Load(pageSource)`

`pageSource` is a string variable of the HTML page. I need to pass the page source as a string, not as a file and not as a URL. How do I do this?

```vb
Dim ids As New List(Of String)()
Dim pageSource = getHtml(url)

Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()

htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = True


htmlDoc.Load(pageSource)


Dim s As HtmlNodeCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/@id")

For Each div As HtmlNode In s
    ids.Add(div.Id)
Next
```

Comment: @minitech if you remove the C# tag you don't have to format for VB.NET

Comment: @jcolebrand: I know, but [tag:c#] is important to let people know that a C# answer is acceptable.

Comment: @minitech how do you figure? This is .NET, but it still needs to be tailored to the VB.NET of the original question. Most people who write .NET code get hung up on one language and don't know how to convert between the two (source: experience)

Comment: @jcolebrand: Well, I assume that's what the tags for. That's why the people who do know tag questions [tag:c#] and [tag:vb.net] :)

Comment: I thought it would be applicable to both

Comment: If there is no mention of C# whatsoever, not even C# code, then IMO the [c#] tag isn't very appropriate even though it's one of the other popular .NET/CLR languages. If you're asking a question that only involves VB.NET programming, tag it [vb.net].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `LoadHtml` instead of `Load`:

```
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(pageSource)
```

[See also the source.](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/98677#1003091)

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/98677#1003091 Source in case anyone is curious, but I'm trolling the page for the headers related to loading from a string on .Load()